# Why use the getter method when we can directly use the setter method to access the private variable in Java?

Tags: java, setter, private-members

```
class Test
{
private int c;
int setc(int i)
{c=i;
return c;
}
/*int getc()
{
return c;
}*/
}
class GetSetEx
{public static void main(String args[])
{Test ob=new Test();//Test class object instantiation
System.out.println(ob.setc(100));//accessing c using setter
}
} 
//Output: 100
```

**I'm able to access value of variable c without using getter method and
by just returning it in the setter method itself**

Comment: Because a getter allows you to return a value without changing it.

Comment: Your program becomes modular by having separate getters and setters as you can put separate logic for each of them.

Comment: I wouldn't have returned a value from the setter method. However, as is, you can't access the original value of the private variable with the setter.

Comment: How could you get the value of `c` without changing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a large system you may be required to access c, without first having to set the value this would not be possible using only a setter. You could not pass a null value or else you would encounter a NullPointerException, to combat this you'd have to catch the exception and by that point, you'd be as well coding the getter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that, but it is bad programming practice. Good programming convention is to generate getters/setters for all private members. Code you wrote is hard to debug in large scale projects with hundreds lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `ob.setc(100)`, you don't need return c, because you already have `100` value.

You can simplify that using:
`System.out.println(100);`

Why could you want a setter also using your example?

Usually getters and setters are useful when you set once the value, and in another place, in later time, you need retrieve the value, without needing setting again.